# How to generate transit route(s) between two locations with GTFS data for a python folium application

Tags: python, geolocation, folium, gtfs

I am trying to create a Python application where I can display the best possible route(s) from one bus stop to another bus stop. I am new to GTFS but I have a basic understanding of the working of the GTFS data. I am trying to figure out how I can obtain the optimal routes along with the shapes of the route between two bus stops to plot in my folium map.

I have tried to a previously answered [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80474/using-gtfs-data-to-create-transit-route?newreg=8ffab3c56e0a442a8e49f666798703f9) here, but most of the links provided for the question are not working for me, I am not able to figure out why. There seems to be not much content on the internet about this scenario also.

Can someone give me some direction or links to some working tutorials?